# Can I avoid this permanent redirect to fix or add a slug?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, seo, asp.net-mvc-routing, slug, redirecttoaction

I am writing a website in MVC 4, and would like to duplicate in part Stack Exchange's style for routing questions. For example:

[stackoverflow.com/questions/15191392](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15191392) and
[stackoverflow.com/questions/15191392/not-the-real-title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15191392/not-the-real-title) and
[stackoverflow.com/questions/15191392/can-i-avoid-this-redirect-to-fix-or-add-a-slug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15191392/can-i-avoid-this-redirect-to-fix-or-add-a-slug)

all route to the same question and correct the URL. I would like the slug to always be present and correct, even though it's unnecessary for routing.

This is my current implementation:

```
routes.MapRoute("Item", "{id}/{slug}/{action}",
                new {controller = "Item", action = "Index", slug = UrlParameter.Optional},
                new { id = @"\d+", slug = @"(?-i)[-a-z]*", action = @"(?-i)(|[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*)" });
routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new {controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional});
```

In `ItemController.cs`:

```
public ActionResult Index(int id, string slug = null)
{
    var item = GetItem(id);
    var itemSlug = ToSlug(item.Title);
    if (slug != itemSlug)
    {
        return RedirectToActionPermanent("Index", new {id, slug = itemSlug});
    }
    return View(item);
}
```

My concern is with the redirection if the slug is wrong/missing. This implementation can require twice as much work (querying the item by ID and slug-ify the title) as necessary to resolve to a view. What's even worse is that I need to duplicate the redirection code for each of my actions.

Is there a better implementation I can use, with regards to code duplication, performance, and SEO impact?

Comment: You should store the slug in the database because if the title changes you want the URL to stay the same. Also, ToSlug might change.

Comment: @usr, apparently I didn't read carefully enough. I **assumed** slug was in db.

Comment: @usr Why would I want the slug to stay the same? Isn't the point of a slug informational? The old URLs will still work, but will be permanently redirected to the URL with the new slug.

Comment: For SEO reasons, and because URLs are supposed to identify a resource and not change. You don't want multiple URLs for the same object (although it works). I think of a URL as a primary key.

Comment: @usr I just confirmed that when a question's title is changed in SE, the slug changes as well. I know SE has been extremely conscious about SEO performance, for what it's worth.

Comment: Well, the gold standard is to identify the page *just* by the slug and not have any number in the URL at all. In that case you definitely want a unique, stable slug.

Comment: I've done a lot of work with SEO. as in many hundreds of hours. If the URL changes at all, you have lost, at least, Google re-adjusting. and often you have split Google juice between the range of possible URL's. Ideally, you want a solution where the bots see only 1 URL ever.

Answer (score 0):

just implement rel="canonical" tags for your pages... this is good anyways because by default google treats your plain domain and www version as 2 different sites but it will help you out here because google will understand all the duplicates you may display are actually all copies of the one canonical version (i would use the pretty slug format) and any links that are built to any of the duplicates will all be credited to the correct pretty url and it will be the ones they show in the search results pages

you can read more about the tag and its implementation here:
http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=139394